# Attach categories to another object

Tags: multi-select

I have two objects called category and members. Category object contains several categories. Now in the member object I placed a multipick  list because a member can have more than one categories. So I want to list all the categories from category object and fill the value of multipick list in member object. can anybody suggest the best solution on this.

[image]

Comment: `Category object contains several categories.` means records.. you want to get all category records and display in member multi picklist ?

Comment: Yes exactly. but I have another object called members and in that I have so many fields now I want to add the multipicklist without disturbing those fields. I mean if visual-force is a solution than I dont want to move another fields to vf if possible.

Comment: then you need VF page here.. you need override you member new page with VF page

Comment: Yes Ratan but its not advisory to move some of 20 existing fields to vf for only adding a multi-pick list. Can I mix the standard page and VF so I can display only multi

Comment: You can't add a VF page in standard edit page layout.. Only option is go with VF page.. Use fieldset for displaying fields in VF page so your code will be sorter you don't need to write code for complete fields